# Calling RegisterClass from C#?

Tags: c#, registerclass

I am trying to create a window (not a WinForm) using CreateWindowEx and RegisterClass. I have figured out how to use CreateWindowEx, but I am stuck on a few things with RegisterClass. In the WNDCLASS struct, how do I set these:

WNDPROC lpfnWndProc
It is a handle to the WndProc method that I want to have in C#.

HINSTANCE hInstance
What is this a handle to? What is the "instance" in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINSTANCE is the handle to your module (dll).
WNDPROC is a function pointer that will be called with window messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can [P/Invoke it](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/RegisterClassEx.html), but why? What are you doing?

A Form is a window that handles that work for you.